# Swap custom frameBuffer with NSOpenglContext

Tags: macos, opengl, render, framebuffer

I'm developing a OpenGL application on Mac OSX.
I have created a framebuffer object and I have rendered on it. (my framebuffer is one back buffer).

How can I now swap my framebuffer and framebuffer created into NSOpenglContext for rendering to screen another scene?
I can't find a method to bind context buffer.